# .setState(): Filtering a person from an array of objects on button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the code below, I am trying to remove a person from what will eventually be an org chart when the delete button next to their name is clicked. At the moment, nothing happens. The closest I've come is all 5 people being deleted when any one of the delete buttons is clicked, but I only want the one person deleted who's button is clicked. I feel like I'm making more of a JS error than a React error.

[See the full code sandbox here.](https://codesandbox.io/s/N9zG0kA56)

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

```
    import React from "react";
import { Component } from "react";

const list = [
  {
    name: "Person 1",
    phone: "123-4567",
    itemId: 11
  },
  {
    name: "Person 2",
    phone: "123-4567",
    itemId: 12
  },
  {
    name: "Person 3",
    phone: "123-4567",
    itemId: 23
  },
  {
    name: "Person 4",
    phone: "123-4567",
    itemId: 34
  },
  {
    name: "Person 5",
    phone: "123-4567",
    itemId: 45
  }
];

class Entry extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      list: list
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    this.setState({
      list: this.state.list.filter(function(person) {
        return person !== e.target.value;
      })
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.list.map(item =>
          <tr key={item.itemId}>
            <td>
              {item.name}
            </td>
            <td>
              {item.phone}
            </td>
            <td>
              <a className="delete" onClick={this.handleClick} />
            </td>
          </tr>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Entry;
```

Comment: what value are you expecting e.target.value to be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your click event has no value, you can pass the itemId:

```
onClick={() => this.handleClick(item.itemId)}
```

Then your `handleClick` should look like:

```
handleClick(itemId) {
    this.setState({
      list: this.state.list.filter(function(person) {
        return person.itemId !== itemId;
      })
    });
  }
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/mo2l8z7469

Comment: This does the trick. Basic JS error on my part. Thank you very much CD.

Answer (score 1):

Both the above solution violates one of the best practices or I should say essential practices of react, that we should use `property initializer syntax`, which is passing the function defined above instead of passing an arrow function inside prop you can read it here in last paragraph of https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html

```
class Entry extends Component {
  /* your handler method */
  handleDelete(itemId){
    return () => {
      this.setState({
        /* logic to filter deleted item from old state */
      });
    }
  }
  /* render method */
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {/* passing onDelete callback */}
        <a className="delete" onClick={this.handleClick(item.id)} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Anshul, thank you very much for this response, THIS is what I was trying to do originally...I think lol. I've seen examples where the method is passed simply with `this.methodName`, and I couldn't figure out what I was doing wrong. Obviously, I failed to pass any argument to `handleClick`, but this is what I was aiming for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```js
//import React from 'react';
//import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const list = [
  {
    name: "Person 1",
    phone: "123-4567",
    itemId: 11
  },
  {
    name: "Person 2",
    phone: "123-4567",
    itemId: 12
  },
  {
    name: "Person 3",
    phone: "123-4567",
    itemId: 23
  },
  {
    name: "Person 4",
    phone: "123-4567",
    itemId: 34
  },
  {
    name: "Person 5",
    phone: "123-4567",
    itemId: 45
  }
];

class Entry extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      list: list
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(item) {
    let filterList = this.state.list.filter((user) => {
       if(user.itemId === item.itemId) {
          return false;
       }
       return true;
    })
    this.setState({
      list: filterList
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <table>
      <tbody>
        {this.state.list.map(item =>
          <tr key={item.itemId}>
            <td>
              {item.name}
            </td>
            <td>
              {item.phone}
            </td>
            <td>
              <button className="delete" onClick={() => this.handleClick(item)} >Del</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        )}
        </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
   <Entry />,
   document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```css
delete
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```